# how to add a button in last cell in Tableview

Tags: uitableview

if any one knows how to add a button in last cell in table view then let me know thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

Just like any cell but have it do what you intended your button to do in cellforrowatindexpath . you can also style the cells anyway you like, even like a button.